# Openssl ECDSA : private key passphrase

Tags: security, encryption, openssl, ecdsa

I am new with Openssl i have generated a private key myprivatekey.pem and a publickey mypublickey.pem with :

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp160k1 -noout -out myprivatekey.pem
```

and my public key with :

```
openssl -ec  -in myprivatekey.pem -pubout -out mypublickey.pem
```

What i want to do next is to encrypte my ecdsa with a passphrase private key and make a certification request for my public key and thank you for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would seem that `ecparam` doesn't have a built-in option for encrypting the generated key. Instead, you can simply do the following:

```
openssl ec -in myprivatekey.pem -out myprivatekey_encrypted.pem -aes256
```

Compared to `genrsa`, an extra step is required, but this basically does the same thing.

---

Now as far as the certificate request, the command is pretty much the same regardless of the type of private key used:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key myprivatekey.pem -out mycertrequest.pem
```

You can then take the resulting `mycertrequest.pem` and send it to a CA for signing.

---

**Edit:**

If you have concerns about writing the unencrypted private key to disk, you can do both the generation and encryption of the key in one step like so:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -aes256 -out privatekey.pem
```

This generates a P-256 key, then prompts you for a passphrase. The key is then encrypted using AES256 and saved into `privatekey.pem`.

Answer (score 6):

While `ecparam` doesn't have an option to encrypt the generated key, `genpkey` can generate ECC private keys and does have such an option:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:secp160k1 -aes-256-cbc -out myprivatekey_encrypted.pem
```

The `-aes-256-cbc` option specifies to encrypt it (with aes-256-cbc; other options are available for different types of encryption).

You can pass `-passin pass:password` or `-passin file:mypassword.pass` to specify the password on the commandline.

Comment: how can you decrypt it?

Comment: `openssl ec -in XXX.encrypted.pem -out XXXX.pem`